# Storing element in string

Tags: c, string, loops, io, scanf

Question: In my code, what ever I enter for n, compiler allows me to input and output only half of it. Why?

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
int main()
{   
    int n; 
    scanf("%d\n",&n);   
    char *c= (char*)malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char));
    c[n]='\0';
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    { 
        scanf("%c",&c[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%c",c[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of pressing Enter one character at a time, enter it continuously.

Comment: Remember: Enter (`'\n'`) is a character as well!

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
scanf("%c",&c[i]);
```

to this:

```
scanf(" %c",&c[i]);
```

Sample output:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ gcc -Wall main.c 
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
5
a
b
c
d
e
abcde
```

I discuss the reasoning behind this solution in [Caution when reading char with scanf (C)](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/caution-when-reading-char-with-scanf-c/).

---

PS: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) No!

Also since you dynamically allocated memory, do not forget to [free()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/) it at the end of your `main()`, like this:

```
free(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Ques.** compiler allows you to input only half of array size, Why?

**Reason of problem :**

```
scanf("%c",&c[i])          //Here %c takes enter key also as a part of input which reduces the input size to half.
```

So, there are mainly 2 solution to your problem:

**Sol. 1** => you only need to include whitespace,rest code would be same.

`scanf(" %c",c[i])           //use whitespace before %c`

**Sol. 2** => Don't enter one character at a time,please enter whole input as a bunch at once then press enter.

Comment: @ankit  if you found any answer is worked for you & helful to understand your problem also..then you should accept that one ,so that community know the solution to this problem..  :)